# Pycharm shortcut for bracket completion

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

I love using PyCharm.  However, can someone please tell me how to quickly move my cursor beyond an auto-completed attribute?  For example:

```
# if I type...

mydict['
```

PyCharm automatically completes the attribute for me...

```
mydict['foobar']
```

But leaves my cursor where the * is...

```
mydict['foobar*']
```

Leaving me the laborious task of typing out the "'" and the "]" to move beyond the attribute.

Is there a shortcut to move the cursor beyond the attribute so I can just keep typing new code, rather than having to manually type out the rest of the attribute?

I hope that makes sense!  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just press <kbd>end</kbd> or (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>--></kbd> for Mac).

```
mydict['foobar|']
              ^ cursor position
```

Key Press <kbd>end</kbd> or (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>--></kbd> for Mac)

```
mydict['foobar']|
                ^ cursor position
```

Also <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, which is probably the fastest hand movement.